# IDA PRO 6.5 LNK1104 error

Tags: ida

I am green to IDA pro and any help would be appreciated!

my efforts:
My end goal would be to write(compile) my own helloworld plugin which I also found in the IDASDK.

I am unable to accomplish that as I always get hit by a LNK1104 cannot open file xxx.plw error even after following the visual++ readme closely.

- I am using Idaq.exe on a 32 bit windows 7 pc
- Microsoft visual C++ 2013

any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: In my linux setup, directly under the IDA directory (where idaq is located) is a subdirectory "plugins", where I will put all my plugin there.   Did you have that?

Comment: @PeterTeoh yea i have that.

Comment: LNK1104 cannot open file xxx.plw  this mostly means your plugin is loaded or has an open referance do you have ida open when you are compiling with an old version of your plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by going to project > properties > configuration properties > general > platform toolset > (drop down) visual studio 2013 - windows XP(v120_xp)

hope this helps